# Is there any way to stop an Ender Pearl from falling?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I need to stop Ender Pearls from falling in Survival mode for a redstone mechanism. Water and Lava slow down their falling, however this won't completely stop them and Cobwebs don't have any effect at all. And I can't find a block or entity that will stop them, as they would break on contact.
**So is there any way to stop Ender Pearls from falling on Survival mode?**

Comment: You can try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVcWgHGKz84

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to actually suspend it in mid-air, but it should be possible to let it bounce on a slime block, by extending and retracting it at just the right timing.

I don't have any experience with this though, but in theory this should be possible. You first have to make sure that the pearl is falling straight down, either using water or whatever, then you can use the slimeblock extension and retraction to let it bounce for eternity.